# How to remove the behaviour of 3D cursor

Tags: 3d-cursor

The behaviour of holding shift and right click moving the the 3D cursor ?
Can't find anything in keymap, like it don't exist.
Any ideas ?
I want to change hotkeys.

ps - I don't want this behaviour, can it be done

Or even better, how to toggle on and off the 3d cursor with a hotkey

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about cursor not being in keymap... It should be here if you try to use search for it and you can change it to whatever you wish

[image]

Comment: That's the very first thing I tried, that's just the placement (which I only really need) it's the removing the behaviour of "movement" shift and left click. I was wanting to make a pie menu for shift left click but I can't because the 3D cursor seems to be hard coded into shift left click.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete this thread, fml all I had to do was create a hotkey with shift and right click and it overrides the hardcoded cursor behaviour ><
So annoying haha.